# BSONDocument from JSON string

Tags: json, scala, reactivemongo

Anyone know how convert a json string in `BSONDocument` with ReactiveMongo driver ?

It looks like apply function for `jsonString` who existing in the official Mongo Scala driver is not existing for now with reactive Driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to convert a JSON `String` to a `BSONDocument`. If working with JSON, the [JSON pack](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/json/overview.html) is recommanded, which leads to be able to convert any `JsValue` to a `BSONValue`.